# exsheets vs. siunitx

Tags: siunitx, exsheets

I want to use `\vary` from [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) and `\SI` from [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). The `\SI` macro parses the first argument (it wants a number), but can it disable with `parse-numbers=false`, but in this case the `\SI` doesn't format the number. (In my example doesn't appear a small space between `2` and `3`.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[per=frac,decimalsymbol=comma,expproduct=cdot]{siunitx}
\usepackage[load-headings,load-tasks,]{exsheets}
%
\begin{document}
\section{Exam-test}
\SetVariations{2}
\variant{1}
\begin{question}
    What is 
    % Does not work: $\SI{\vary{1000}{2000}}{m}$ 
    % Works:
    $\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\vary{12345}{23456}}{m}$  
    in centimeters?
    Check the small space between 2 and 3: $\SI{12345}{m}$
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

How can I use them together?

Comment: `\vary` is not expandable. This would work: `\vary{\SI{12345}{m}}{\SI{23456}{m}}`

Comment: Yes, I'm using this form too. So it's impossible to use a simpliest method. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an interface to `\vary{\SI{12345}{m}}{\SI{23456}{m}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[per=frac,decimalsymbol=comma,expproduct=cdot]{siunitx}
\usepackage[load-headings,load-tasks,]{exsheets}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\varySI}{mm}
 {% #1 are the values, #2 is the unit
  \uzsolt_vary_si:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_uzsolt_values_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \uzsolt_vary_si:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_uzsolt_values_tl
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_uzsolt_values_tl { {\SI{##1}{#2}} }
   }
  \exp_last_unbraced:NV \exsheets_vary:w \l_uzsolt_values_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Exam-test}
\SetVariations{2}
\variant{1}
\begin{question}
    What is 
    $\varySI{{12345}{23456}}{m}$  
    in centimeters?
\end{question}
\variant{2}
\begin{question}
    What is 
    $\varySI{{12345}{23456}}{m}$  
    in centimeters?
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

I assume here that the unit is the same for all the variants, but it's possible to incorporate the unit with some more work. However, in that case the syntax wouldn't be really much different from typing

```
\vary{\SI{12345}{m}}{\SI{23456}{m}}
```

which maybe is the simplest approach.

[image]

*Comment* I find bad the syntax of `\vary`, with a number of arguments depending on the number of variants.

Comment: It should be `\m` instead of `m` for the unit, now that you are using [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) anyway.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Why `\m`? I'm sure that `\SI{1}{m}` is valid `siunitx` syntax.

Comment: The two approaches give identical outputs but `\m` is a predefined unit in `siunitx`. (It's the same as if you want the unit to be micrometers, you write `\um` instead of `μm`.)

Comment: Wow... great. I'll try to understand. Thank you!