# How to change the decimal separator in exsheets to comma

Tags: exsheets

In the exsheets package the default decimal separator is dot. How can I change it to a comma?

Comment: Currently that's not possible, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Perhaps you can use `exsheets` in conjunction with `siunitx`, as in this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214804/exsheets-vs-siunitx, and set the `siunitx` decimal seperator to a comma.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it might or might not work to say `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_set_protected:Npn \exsheets_num:n #1 { \num {#1} } \ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396982/4011 for an updated answer.